# Can't create cloudsql role for Service Account via api

Tags: python-requests, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to use the api to create service accounts in GCP.

To create a service account I send the following post request:

```
base_url = f"https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/serviceAccounts"
auth = f"?access_token={access_token}"
data = {"accountId": name}
# Create a service Account
r = requests.post(base_url + auth, json=data)
```

this returns a 200 and creates a service account:

Then, this is the code that I use to create the specific roles:

```
sa = f"{name}@dotmudus-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
sa_url = base_url + f'/{sa}:setIamPolicy' + auth
data = {"policy":
    {"bindings": [
        {
            "role": roles,
            "members":
                [
                    f"serviceAccount:{sa}"
                ]
        }
    ]}
}
```

If roles is set to one of `roles/viewer`, `roles/editor` or `roles/owner` this approach does work.
However, if I want to use, specifically `roles/cloudsql.viewer` The api tells me that this option is not supported.

Here are the roles.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

I don't want to give this service account full viewer rights to my project, it's against the principle of least privilege.

**How can I set specific roles from the api?**

EDIT:

here is the response using the resource manager api: with `roles/cloudsql.admin` as the role

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}:setIamPolicy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "policy": {
  "bindings": [
   {
    "members": [
     "serviceAccount:sa@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    ],
    "role": "roles/cloudsql.viewer"
   }
  ]
 }
}


{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloudresourcemanager.projects.v1beta1.ProjectIamPolicyError",
        "type": "SOLO_REQUIRE_TOS_ACCEPTOR",
        "role": "roles/owner"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem here. How did you solved this problem?

Comment: I solved this by extracting the entire policy object via, roles.get. Then appending the required role to the object and calling this api with data = the entire json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code provided it appears that you are appending to the first `base_url` which is not the correct context to modify project roles.

This will try to place the appended path to: `https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project}/serviceAccount`

The POST path for adding roles needs to be: `https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project]:setIamPolicy`

If you remove `/serviceAccounts` from the `base_url` and it should work.

**Edited response to add more information due to your edit**

OK, I see the issue here, sorry but I had to set up a new project to test this.

`cloudresourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy` needs to replace the entire policy.  It appears that you can add constraints to what you change but that you have to submit a complete policy in json for the project.

Note that `gcloud` has a `--log-http` option that will help you dig through some of these issues.  If you run

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member serviceAccount:$NAME --role roles/cloudsql.viewer --log-http
```

It will show you how it pulls the existing existing policy, appends the new role and adds it.

I would recommend using the [example code provided here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy) to make these changes if you don't want to use gcloud or the console to add the role to the user as this could impact the entire project.

Hopefully they improve the API for this need.

Comment: Please see my updated question. It seems like I have the wrong format for creating roles for service accounts. Although I can't find any better documentation.

Comment: I added more info to my post due to a lack of space in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the `--log-http option`. Really helpful.